# Change an SQL server express table name

Tags: sql-server-express

Hi I am using Visual Studio 2008 and I have an .mdf in the app_data of my ASP.NET MVC project.. I was trying to change the name of a table through the properties in the server explorer but it is greyed out. Is it possible to change the name?

I can see that you can copy the table but I am unsure on how to then paste a copy of it somewhere??

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double click the .mdf file. Then it will be opened in the Server Explorer. Right-click your table and choose "Open Table Definition". Then open the "Properties" window - the first property is "(Name)" - change it and save the table - That's it!

Comment: Ah right, I was right clicking the table name in the server explorer while the definition was open and it was greyed out.. clicked the property window as you said and worked fine thanks.